# Render multiple times in a single pass using the Geometry Shader (openGL)

Tags: c++, opengl

I am using an orthographic projection when doing a rendering of the scene. I am rendering on a texture of resolution 128x128. Now I would like to render to other textures that have that same resolution but I want to get different details. The picture I posted may clear things out

[image]

As you can see there is a grey scene and 3 cameras rendering the same thing but with different distance and viewplane size. Since the 3 are going to render on 3 textures of the same resolution, those textures are going to contain the same information but with different amount of detail.

I can do this in 3 passes and redefine the camera before each rendering. However, since the view is the same, only closer, I guess there might be some way of using the geometry shader to overcome this and do it in a single pass. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With [layered rendering](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Geometry_Shader#Layered_rendering), you can do that in one pass. However, you would have the geomety shader do multiply the primitives for every layer (while applying a different transformation to each "copy", of course).

However, you cannot directly render into 3 different texture objects. For layered rendering to work, you would need some layered texture object like an [array texture](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Array_Texture). Since all your textures are the same size, you could probably use a single array texture with 3 layers instead of 3 separate 2D textures, but I can't say for sure if that will fit your use case.

Comment: In theory I think one can create a 2d array texture view referencing three normal 2d textures, and then attach the view to as a layered color attachment onto a FBO. In practice using an array directly is probably a better choice anyhow.

Comment: Can I also extend this to 3d textures by using imageStore instead of outputting a fragcolor?

Comment: @tigeradol: well, not in any useful way. The key point here is that you need a separate rasterization for each view. You can of course use image store to write to an arbitrary position in an image, but what color would you write in a single fragment shader invocation? That doesn't really make sense. It would only slightly make sense if the object you want to draw is extremely simple, like a textured quad, so that each view is just sampling the texture at a different location. But you were better of using multiple render targets, then.